# How to get a checkmark for one element

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, foreach

```
struct TimeZoneView: View {

    @State private var favorite = false
    @State private var timezone: String = ""

    private var timeZoneIdentifiers = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false, content: {
                VStack(spacing: 25) {
                    selection
                    Spacer()
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Property  “favourite" to select  favorite country
Property timezone for transferring a country's city name
timeZoneIdentifiers array of strings that is systemic for swiftui from which I get the country names

createSelection function for displaying and accepting data

```
    func createSelection(
        title: String,
        clicked: (() -> Void)?,
        favorite: Bool
    ) -> some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                clicked?()
            }, label: {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(title)
                                .font(.custom(.semiBold, size: 16))
                                .foregroundColor(.theme.appBlack)
                            Spacer()
                            if favorite {
                                Image.app.addPurple
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 16,height: 16)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(20)
                    }
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .stroke(Color.theme.grayProfileText, lineWidth: 0.5)
                    )
                    .padding([.leading,.trailing], 20)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

“selection"  to be displayed

ForEach that I do in the middle of “selection"

goes through the entire collection of country names

clicking on a selected country will trigger events such as assigning a timezone to the country's city name and a toggle to select that country

```
    var selection: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(timeZoneIdentifiers, id: \.self) { zone in
                let temp = zone.components(separatedBy: "/")
                if temp.count >= 2 {
                    let cityName = temp[1].replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ")
                    createSelection(title: zone, clicked: {
                        timezone = cityName
                        favorite.toggle()
                    }, favorite: favorite)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I can't choose just one country selects all

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `Bool` affects every cell, a better way is to keep the (selected) time zone in `favorite`

1. Declare `favorite` as empty `String`

   ```
   @State private var favorite = ""
   ```
2. Change the related (bound) types also to `String`.
3. in `createSelection` replace `if favorite {` with `if favorite == title {`.
4. In `selection` replace `favorite.toggle()` with `favorite = zone`.